# Regarding installation of Ubuntu in phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have a Nokia 5230 mobile can I install the ubuntu in it?

Answer (score 0):

No, Ubuntu OS & Ubuntu touch can only be installed on phone which has android.
No Nokia Symbian phones, No Lumia(Windows) phones, No Apple Iphones. Only on phones which are capable of Android (With dual core processor & minimum of 512mb INTERNAL RAM).